# How do I add the facebook login UI to my React Native app?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

I set up my xcode project to use the facebook libraries succesfully i think. I have the following code in my index.ios.js file:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken
} = FBSDK;

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    alert(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});


export default class FacebookReactNativeTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FacebookReactNativeTest', () => FacebookReactNativeTest);
```

Sadly, the Facebook login stuff isn't appearing on the view here, but the stuff in FacebookReactNativeTest is. It seems I am not adding the Login var that is created to the view and since I am new to React Native I am not sure how to add it manually. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this is how it should be done:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  LoginButton,
  AccessToken
} = FBSDK;

var Login = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                alert("login has error: " + result.error);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("login is cancelled.");
              } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                    alert(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
                )
              }
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});



export default class FacebookReactNativeTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
         <Text>Welcome to the Facebook SDK for React Native!</Text>
        <Login />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('FacebookReactNativeTest', () => FacebookReactNativeTest);
```